# Read/write/browse files from client side *desktop* Meteor app?

Tags: node.js, meteor, fs, electron

*(I am new to Meteor and NodeJs environments)*

I would like to implement a Meteor-based webapp which needs to read/write/browse files on the client's local filesystem. I used the Meteor package [`arboleya:electrify`](https://github.com/arboleya/electrify) to make the client side webapp a desktop app, with the hope of having the access rights to read the filesystem (because if [Atom](https://atom.io/) can do it, then why not my app).

My problem so far is that I don't understand how I can use an API like NodeJs's fs from a Meteor client.

**Edit:** This question is for a client Meteor app, connected to a remote Meteor server.

Comment: cool package! I've never used it, but I suppose the server piece of meteor will be running in that app as well (it kind of has to if it standalone). So then of course you can just use `fs` from node (in the server files). Just add `meteorhacks:npm` and then use `var fs = Meteor.npmRequire('fs')` and off you go doing whatever you want with `fs` as in node itself.

Comment: I am in the client side only, I edited my question to include this information. My attempts to include node's fs via your approach in the client failed, maybe because I am a clueless beginner, maybe because I am on the client.

Comment: Npm.require() seems to be only usable on the server. People pointed me to the direction of webpack if I want to include npm packages from the client side.

Comment: `arboleya:electrify` is going to be updated to allow sending messages between the Electron process and the Meteor process, so it likely will be the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent versions of [Electrify](https://github.com/arboleya/electrify) enable an easy IPC connection between Electron's NodeJS and Meteor as RPC, allowing the Meteor client to remotely call the functions of Electron's NodeJS.